# How does the default comparator work in C#?

Tags: c#, linq, sorting, comparator

I'm using OrderBy for some sorting based on properties and I found the [documentation for the default comparer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azhsac5f.aspx) but it didn't explain much to me.  If an object doesn't implement `System.IComparable<T>`, how does it generate a `Comparer<T>`?

For instance, I'm currently sorting a list of objects based a property value of type `object`. They are numeric types underneath and the sorting works fine.  How does C#/Linq know how to sort the object?  Does it do some un-boxing into primitives? Does it do some hash checking?  How would that translate into greater than or less than?

If they were a more complex type would this fail with an error or would OrderBy do nothing, or would it even sort in a way that made no sense?

Comment: This post of Jon Skeet, can be useful for you http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2011/01/05/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-26b-orderby-descending-thenby-descending/ . Actually, the entire series of EduLinq is nice to read and understand a lof of concepts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well you can check the reference source and [see for yourself](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/comparer.cs,78f450d4aef50299,references) what it does.

```
    public static Comparer<T> Default {
        get {
            Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<Comparer<T>>() != null);

            Comparer<T> comparer = defaultComparer;
            if (comparer == null) {
                comparer = CreateComparer();
                defaultComparer = comparer;
            }
            return comparer;
        }
    }
    private static Comparer<T> CreateComparer() {
        RuntimeType t = (RuntimeType)typeof(T);

        // If T implements IComparable<T> return a GenericComparer<T>
#if FEATURE_LEGACYNETCF
        //(SNITP)
#endif
            if (typeof(IComparable<T>).IsAssignableFrom(t)) {
                return (Comparer<T>)RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstanceForAnotherGenericParameter((RuntimeType)typeof(GenericComparer<int>), t);
            }

        // If T is a Nullable<U> where U implements IComparable<U> return a NullableComparer<U>
        if (t.IsGenericType && t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>)) {
            RuntimeType u = (RuntimeType)t.GetGenericArguments()[0];
            if (typeof(IComparable<>).MakeGenericType(u).IsAssignableFrom(u)) {
                return (Comparer<T>)RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstanceForAnotherGenericParameter((RuntimeType)typeof(NullableComparer<int>), u);
            }
        }
        // Otherwise return an ObjectComparer<T>
      return new ObjectComparer<T>();
    }
```

So what it does is it checks if the type implements `IComparable<T>`, if it does it uses the comparer built in to the type (your list of objects that are numeric types would follow this branch). It then does the same check again in case the type is a `Nullable<ICompareable<T>>`. If that also fails it uses the `ObjectComparer` which uses `Comparer.Default`.

[Here is the Compare code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/R/0b849d3a25d23f17.html) for `Comparer.Default`

```
    public int Compare(Object a, Object b) {
        if (a == b) return 0;
        if (a == null) return -1;
        if (b == null) return 1;
        if (m_compareInfo != null) {
            String sa = a as String;
            String sb = b as String;
            if (sa != null && sb != null)
                return m_compareInfo.Compare(sa, sb);
        }

        IComparable ia = a as IComparable;
        if (ia != null)
            return ia.CompareTo(b);

        IComparable ib = b as IComparable;
        if (ib != null)
            return -ib.CompareTo(a);

        throw new ArgumentException(Environment.GetResourceString("Argument_ImplementIComparable"));
    }
```

As you can see it checks if `a` or `b` implements `IComparable` and if neither do it throws a exception.

Comment: Thank you.  I now know about Reference Source

Answer (score 1):

Browsing on [Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/comparer.cs,70109a31a5908e0c), it returns an `ObjectComparer<T>`, which is a special internal type that just delegates the work to `System.Collections.Comparer.Default`.

This, in turn, throws an exception if it receives parameters that do not implement `IComparable`. Since that comparer works through downcasting and reflection, then it does not care if the static type of the object does not implement `IComparable` (which is the case if you have a list of `object`s).

So the bottom line is this: first it checks for `IComparable<T>`, then it checks for `IComparable`, and finally it throws an exception.

By the way, most (I'd say all even) built-in types implement `IComparable<T>` in some way, so that's how they can be sorted.

Answer (score 0):

`int`, or to be more precise, `Int32` *does* actually implement `IComparable`, so it works. ([source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/int32.cs,225942ed7b7a3252))

`OrderBy` appears to attempt to use the comparator for the first type it comes across, so if you start with an object that doesn't implement `IComparable`, you will get an `ArgumentException`:

> At least one object must implement IComparable

If you start with say, an `Int32`, then you will get the same exception with:

> Object must be of type `Int32`

From the comparer for `Int32`

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the internals, if the object is generic and implements `IComparable<T>`, the default comparer will return a `GenericComparer` instance that casts objects to that interface to perform comparisons. Primitive types already implement it. Nullable primitive types automatically implement that interface as well, so the returned `NullableComparer` works similarly. There is no boxing/unboxing in those scenarios.

Otherwise, it will try to cast objects into non-generic `IComparable` instances which can cause boxing with structs or throw an `ArgumentException` if the type does not implement it.